# Mass assignment ignoring undefined attributes in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `MyModel` with attributes `id` and `name`. Normally I can create a new record using

```
my_model = MyModel.new(name: 'Bob')
```

Is there some way I can create a model so it ignores attributes in the hash that don't actually exist on the model? Like this:

```
my_model = MyModel.new(name: 'Bob', something_not_defined: 'Some string')
```

For this example I'm not concerned about mass assignment security. The model is fed a hash that could contain a large number of random values I don't care about, but it still contains a lot of values that map to the model attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite your model's `initialize` method to discard any attribute but the ones you want.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes = attributes.slice(:name)
    super attributes
  end
end
```

This approach can have unexpected results, since Rails won't call `initialize` in every occasion, so I'd better define a `.build` method with that logic in your model and use that instead of `.new` to initialize your models:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.build(attributes = {})
    attributes = attributes.slice(:name)
    new attributes
  end
end
```

And then use it like this:

```
MyModel.build(name: 'Bob', something_not_defined: 'Some string')
```